# Paste the same text into multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I have these data in my Excel spreadsheet in different cells:

Structured Asset Mortgage Investments Trust

0.365% due 09/25/2047
0.403% due 07/19/2035
0.813% due 09/19/2032

And As a result I would like to get these (in a single cell) like this:

Structured Asset Mortgage Investments Trust 0.365% due 09/25/2047
Structured Asset Mortgage Investments Trust 0.403% due 07/19/2035
Structured Asset Mortgage Investments Trust 0.813% due 09/19/2032

Sometimes it is more than 3 cells.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: how would you proceed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all cells that are needed.
str= ''
For 1 to len(cells)
 str = str + '\n' + 'Structured Asset Mortgage Investments Trust ' + cells(1) + cells (2) + cells (3)

excelCellVal =  str

Consider above code as Pseudo .

you can trigger above code as vbscript , macro etc.

Please let me know if you want me to explain code further.

Comment: Yes, could you please explain it further? (I forgot to add, but I hope it's not a complication that sometimes there are more than 3 cells into which I have to paste the same text)

Answer (score 0):

If the "different cells" are A1, A3, A4 and A5 please try:

```
=A1&" "&A3&CHAR(10)&A1&" "&A4&CHAR(10)&A1&" "&A5
```

and wrap text to suit.